# Make a Stored Procedure Atomic without regards to outer transaction

Tags: sql, multithreading, t-sql, stored-procedures

[image]i was looking for a solution but so far no luck.

Description:
I (meaning me as in the company) have a stored procedure that does some fairly fast and small work. Lets call it SP_Small. Its small its fass, it has an update and executes another stored procedure. Therefore trying to make it atomic by combining SELECTS and UPDATES into one select is not really workable. (one proposed solution i stumbled upon)

We have a import mechanism, that imports several different documents parallel into the database.
Each import is inside a transaction (done by the application that launches the imports).
Each import calls the SP_Small to do some importand work.

Problem:
Right now, SP_Small is de facto atomic, but the record it access (and which is shared) remains locked until the outer transaction is commited, making the whole proces Serial, not parallel.

Requirement:
Make the SP_Small atomic, making sure only one process executes it at the same time, but after its executed the rest can run parallel.

This is a simple (and ungly :)) drawing of the problem, hope that helps to clarify:

Comment: Can you just not have an outer transaction? Run each SP_Small in its own root transaction.

Comment: I am afraid the outer transaction is a given, its part of the overall solution. while in THEORY it could change, the change would be considered MAJOR and is frowned upon and problably we would be told: find another way.

Comment: I would read about the various types of locking supported by your sql server. It may help you decide on your solution. I don't understand your question. You say the sp is 'defacto atomic' but later say your requirement is to make it atomic.

Comment: Can you invoke sp_small on a 2nd connection and in a 2nd transaction?

Comment: If I'm reading you properly:  it's not that sp_small isn't atomic (it is), but rather that it's not autonomous.  Autonomous transactions (except logging and some corner cases) break transaction integrity.  If you're sure that it's what you want:  look into [autonomous transactions.](http://www.dbbest.com/blog/autonomous-transactions-sql-server/)

Comment: Jay: trying to read up but not sure what solution the best. The magic word here is experience. SP is not atomic, not sure based on what you think it is, probably i wrote something wrong.
usr: possible option, will look into it, but probably not as the code executed by the Main Application is a scripting language code and it takes the connection from the Main application. Not sure if i can open a 2nd connection.

Answer (score 1):

Making `SP_Small` Autonomous from it's process's outer transaction is one option, but it's not the only option, nor is it likely the preferred one.

Two other options are 1) Change `SP_Small` so that it can perform it's function without being self-blocking or "*serializing*".  This is usually the preferred option.

Or 2) Change the Isolation Level so that it is no-longer self-blocking.  Of course we cannot evaluate the work-ability of either of these without knowing more about `SP_Small` and why it is currently serializing.

Nor are these necessarily the only options, again depending on the details of what's really going on here and what really *needs* to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to run `SP_Small` at the start of your "outer transactions"? The reason Process 1 blocks Process 2 is because Process 1 will hold an exclusive lock on any rows that it updates until it commits. Exclusive locks stop other transactions from even reading those locked rows. Can you run `SP_Small` after the long import mechanism or will that affect the result of the import? Doing that will make each process lock rows for a much smaller period of time. If that's not possible, can you commit the transaction immediately after calling `SP_Small` and undo it some other way if the import mechanism fails?